# Selenium finding video duration and playing video to 10%

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage where there is a video, i want to find that video duration and play that video to 10% of the total time.

I am new to Selenium and searched on google but unable to find the solution. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am giving the generic answer, kindly try on it

```
Webdriver Element = driver.findElement(By.Id("Id of the frame"));
Switch into the frame driver.switchTo().frame(Element);
driver.findElement(By.Id("Element of of play button"))
```

use the action class to mouseover  and capture the duration time

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("movie_player"));
        Action mouseMovement=builder.moveToElement(we).build();
        mouseMovement.perform();

        WebElement durationTime= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(enter the path)));
```

- convert the durationtime into sec
- calculate the percentage
- base on that percentage click on the navigation bar.

Comment: If you're going to copy the code from another answer word-for-word, then you should use the same webdriver variable **driver** instead of **driver1** for consistency purposes.

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your first question.

```
Webdriver Element = driver.findElement(By.Id("Id of the frame"));

//Switch into the frame
driver.switchTo().frame(Element);

//Click on play button
driver.findElement(By.Id("Element of of play button"))
```

Second question will search and update here.

Answer (score 0):

```
*

WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-lightbox");
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Open a Div in Lightbox')]"));
    element.click();
    System.out.println("found element and clicked");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement frameElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/wswxQ3mhwqQ']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label=\'Play\']")).click();
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.className("ytp-progress-bar-container"));
        Action mouseMovement=builder.moveToElement(we).build();
        mouseMovement.perform();
        we.click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebElement titleText=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("ytp-title-link")));
        System.out.println(titleText.getText());
        WebElement time=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.ytp-time-current")));
        System.out.println(time.getText());
```

*

Comment: Please add the explanation of your answer.